# Attempting to post object from frontend to backend. Serialize object in frontend and deserialize object in backend. React C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, json, serialization, deserialization

```
        const [payload, setPayload] = useState({
            Email: null,
            Password: null
          });
        
          const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var json = JSON.stringify(payload);
              
            try {
              const { data } = await axios.post(
                "https://localhost:5001/api/User/Login",
                {
                  json
                }
              );
              console.log(data);
              ctxDispatch({ type: "USER_LOGIN", payload: data });
              localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
              toast.success("Login Successful");
              navigate("/");
            } catch (err) {
              toast.error(getError(err));
            }
          };
        
        
        [AllowAnonymous]
                [HttpPost("Login")]
                public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> Login([FromBody] LoginDTO loginDTO)
                {
                    //LoginDTO loginDTO = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginDTO>(input);
        
                    var pwd = Encrypt.ConvertToEncrypt(loginDTO.Password);
        
                    User currentUser = await _context.user.FirstOrDefaultAsync(user =>
                       user.Email.ToLower() == loginDTO.Email.ToLower()
                       &&`enter code here`
                       user.Password == pwd);
}
    
    
    public class LoginDTO
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

When I post this string to my backend it attempts to parse my string but fails at the first char {. When i send this string wrapped in quotes through swagger it passes with no issues. When i send this string through postman with no quotes wrapped around the string I get the same exact error as i get when posting through my frontend.

Comment: if you want some help, pls replace the images by text.

Comment: I cant post images it says because my reputation is not 10 yet, can you click on the link??

Comment: REMOVE all images and post the text instead. Images are  prohibited by rules here

Comment: @Serge Images are gone. relevant code to the issue is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix the action input parameters, you don't need to deserialize it , it will be deserialized by MVC

```
public async Task< ....([FromBody] LoginDTO loginDto)
```

and since you are sending a json string,  add content type to axios

```
axios.post('..your url', json, {
  headers: {
    // Overwrite Axios's automatically set Content-Type
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Comment: I get an error still when changing this. "System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. To show additional information call EnableSensitiveDataLogging() when overriding DbContext.OnConfiguring.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method19(Closure )"

Comment: @kyleruban I told you already if you need a real helpl, replace images with text code and mark what line gives you this error

Comment: What sqlDataSource  for in your code for?. Also did you check  loginDTO in debugger? Does it have any data except defaults?

Comment: that is connect to my database... I cannot check in my debugger it does not allow me to debug in my application for some reason

Comment: Remove this code since it is not used.  And can you post you LoginDTO class pls too?

Comment: I added the LoginDTO class

Comment: I am debugging the application now and it is saying that the email and password are null when reaching that controller

Comment: @kyleruban Now check it in your javascript code, I think they are null there too

Comment: It is not null in javascript. This is the json string that is being sent to the controller in the payload. Can i send a json string like this to an object input parameter thats in my controller? I have a user with email: 1 and password: 1 just to test quicker.
"{\"Email\":\"1\",\"Password\":\"1\"}"       @Serge

Comment: This is exactly what is shown in the payload. json: "{\"Email\":\"1\",\"Password\":\"1\"}"

Comment: try this code axios.post('....', json, {
  headers: {
    // Overwrite Axios's automatically set Content-Type
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

Comment: I removed this and it sends the populated object but still have null values in my c# debugging

Comment: @kyleruban I am sorry , I updated my answer, don't remove , just add a content type

Comment: I have tried adding content-type and that does not change anything..... @Serge

Comment: @kyleruban Remove {} from {json}

Comment: I have tried all ways you have explained nothing is working ... @Serge

Comment: @kyleruban I am sorry , but I can't help you any more. Try to change loginDTo properties to low case - password, email

Comment: removing the {} around the {json} value worked! Thank you so much! @Serge